# Missing Haskell package dependency: ffi

Tags: haskell, clang, cabal

I'm using Linux Mint (Ubuntu derivat) and want to install libClang with Cabal.

The problem is, that I always get the message: "requires ffi" and then it stops.

I have installed on my system:

- Haskel-Platform 2010.1.0.0.1
- libffi5
- libffi-dev

what is missing?

**edit**

i just make `cabal install libClang`

and then get: `cabal: cannot configure LibClang-0.0.9. It requires ffi -any`

Comment: You need to post the full command you are running and the full error message, to diagnose this. Here's what a [working libclang/haskell build looks like](http://hpaste.org/46641/cabal_install_libclang), *after* installing the C clang package, and greencard from Hackage.

Comment: i just make cabal install libClang and then the first line is: "cabal: cannot configure LibClang-0.0.9. It requires ffi -any"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the [libclang](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/LibClang) package depends on the *Haskell* `ffi` package, a primitive package that ships with GHC 7.x compilers.

You can check if you have the package:

```
$ ghc-pkg list ffi
/home/dons/lib/ghc-7.0.3/package.conf.d
   ffi-1.0
```

**Solution 1:** This package ships with GHC 7, so you will need to upgrade to the Haskell Platform 2011.2.0.1, to get the ffi package.

**Solution 2:** You maybe instead can download the libclang package, and remove the `ffi` dep:

```
$ cd LibClang-0.0.9 
$ vim *.cabal       -- remove the ffi depend.
$ cabal install
```

and it should build fine.

Comment: which system you are using? i switched now to my other PC with fedora core 15 and haskell platform 2011.2.0.0 and ghc 7.0.2 and i get the same error. ghc-pkg list ffi dont print any ffi. can i install it manually?

Comment: Try building with the "ffi" dependency removed.